# carthage update is not work Task failed with exit code 65:

Tags: carthage

I try to use carthage update on xcode 8.3.1 to add the octokit, but when I excute the command `carthage update`, the terminal shows this error:

```
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/xuliner/Downloads/octokit.objc-54474a6947342ddedb4f3dc37ca6e54c050d92bf/Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble/Nimble.xcodeproj -scheme Nimble-iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/xuliner/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/Nimble/v3.2.0 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/vn/c9ppdjg12rn8pj5r093g8_tr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.qEGXw6.log
```

I open the build log and it shows:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

How can I fix that?